# How to find unwanted URL in sting

Tags: php, regex, url

I want to check text for spam URLs. For example here:

```
$str = 'Curabitur aliquet quam page.com Page.Com t e x t . c o m id dui .Posuere curabitur strona quam id dui posuere. Aitur aliquet TEXT.COM quam id dui posuere. A ';
```

I want to find

- `page.com`
- `Page.Com`
- `t e x t . c o m`
- `TEXT.COM`

```
$num_found = preg_match_all($pattern, ($str), $out)
```

but I only find this:

- [0] => `page.com`
- [1] => `t . c`

my regex looks like this

```
$pattern = '|[A-Za-z0-9]+\s*\.{1}\s*([a-z0-9]+)(\s*\.{1}([a-z0-9]+))*|';
```

So I basically look for words then eventual spaces after and before one dot.
And it works, but the thing is it doesn't work for words beginning with capital letters lock or being all capital letters. When I add `[A-Za-z0-9]` to all the words to the regex, it also will match words that are the end of the sentence where the dot is, so it is a wrong solution.

I was thinking about doing another regex to check for caps. But I am not sure what would be the best solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: `{1}` is never necessary in a regexp. Everything matches 1 time unless you quantify it otherwise.

Comment: Try `(?<!\S)(?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:\s[A-Za-z0-9])+\s\.\s[A-Za-z0-9](?:\s[A-Za-z0-9])*|[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)\b`, see https://regex101.com/r/lFqGcJ/1

Comment: It is pretty unclear why you use `[A-Za-z0-9]` and the other time `[a-z0-9]`.  Then first one will also match CAPTIALS, the second one will not. If you change that also `TEXT.COM` will be found, but also some unwanted other things, see: https://regex101.com/r/yfencn/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use an alternation `|` for either matching multiple characters separated by a dot in the first part, or single characters separated by a space or a dot in the second part.

```
(?<!\S)(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z0-9]+|[A-Za-z0-9](?:\h+[A-Za-z0-9])*\h+\.\h+[A-Za-z0-9](?:\h+[A-Za-z0-9])*)(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a111DH/1)

If you want to match multiple times a dot:

```
(?<!\S)(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)+|[A-Za-z0-9](?:\h+[A-Za-z0-9])*(?:\h+\.\h+[A-Za-z0-9](?:\h+[A-Za-z0-9])*)+)(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bpTbJv/1)

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `(?:` Non capture group (*for the alternation `|`*)

  - `[A-Za-z0-9]+` Match 1+ times 1 of the listed ranges in the character class
  - `(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)+` Repeat 1+ times matching a `.` and 1+ times again what is listed in the character class
  - `|` Or
  - `[A-Za-z0-9]` Match a single char from the ranges in the character class
  - `(?:\h+[A-Za-z0-9])*` Optionally repeat 1+ spaces and a single char
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\h+\.\h+[A-Za-z0-9]` Match 1+ spaces, `.` 1+ spaces and again a single char
    - `(?:\h+[A-Za-z0-9])*` Optionally repeat 1+ spaces and a single char
  - `)+` Close the non capture group and repeat it 1 or more times
- `)` Close non capture group
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the right

Comment: Your approach works for me, but one thing I forgot to mention is that I also want to find pages like :
 page . uk, page. uk, page .uk 
I edited the pattern like this: 
```(?<!\S)(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:\s*(\.)\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+(\.)?)+|[A-Za-z0-9](?:\h+[A-Za-z0-9])*(?:\h+\.\h+[A-Za-z0-9](?:\h+[A-Za-z0-9])*)+)(?!\S)```
And I have a problem because I find those pages mentioned above, but also I find the ends of sentences

Comment: @mrTarragona That is right, but how can you tell that `page. uk` is part of a url, and in the sentence `This is a nice page. uk\nis part of co.uk` it is not?

Comment: yeah I guess the only way is to check if the next character after a dot is a capital letter, but that will discard **Page . com** option. That's the only solution I can find to this

Comment: @mrTarragona You might use https://regex101.com/r/8JbODL/1 but I think there is always a chance that you will get false positives.

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe:**

```
(?i)((?:[^.]\s+(?:[a-z0-9._]{1}\s+)+))|(\b[a-z0-9_.]+.com)
```

**Demo:**

- https://regex101.com/r/VprUb2/1

[image]